# Error trying to connect to local host through 'request' module

Tags: node.js

I am getting the following error when I run the code that follows

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
               at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
               at Object.afterConnect (as oncomplete) (net.js:892
```

The code which I was trying test is below:

```
    var async = require('async'),
    request = require('request');

function done(err,results) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    console.log('Done ! results: %j',results);
}


var collection = [1,2,3,4];

function iterator(value,callback) {
    request.post({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080',
        body: JSON.stringify(value)
    }, function (err,res,body){
        if (err) {
            callback(err,body && JSON.parse(body));
        }

    });
}

async.map(collection,iterator,done);
```

Comment: `ECONNREFUSED` means that it failed to connect to the URL that you specify.

Answer (score 0):

As Phoenix said it means NodeJS was not able to connect to `localhost:8080` are you sure you've got an HTTP server on that port?

You can check that with: `curl http://localhost:8080`.